# Trying to delete .cap, .csv files but i get an error

Tags: linux, permissions, csv

I need help on my kali linux.  I tried to delete these files

```
1186047 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19717377 Sep  5 17:54  -01.cap
1186032 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root      576 Sep  5 17:54  -01.csv
1186040 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root      598 Sep  5 17:54  -01.kismet.csv
1186044 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root     3863 Sep  5 17:54  -01.kismet.netxml
```

from my desktop using the `rm` command but it refused. I also tried to change the permission using `chmod` and other command but refused.

Comment: What error do you get when the command is "refused?"  Also, consider https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me, as if this is a difficult problem you may want to consider a distro other than Kali

Answer (score 0):

It looks as those files begin with `-` which means `rm` or other commands are likely to treat them as flags/arguments unless you tell them not to.  The way to do that is, for most commands at least, to ad `--` after the options you want, then all the rest of the arguments will not be treated as special.  For example

```
rm -01.cap
```

is likely interpreted as passing `-0` as an argument to `rm`, which is not a valid option.  You have a couple of options, you could either include the path so the first character is not `-` as in

rm ./-01.cap

or use `--` to signify the end of flags and options like

rm -- -01.cap